# Laravel - Edit and Update Page

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I am trying to create an edit page and call my update method on submit, the problem is I am getting a 404 when updating. This is my blade file for editing like so:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'AdminLTE')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Professions</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
    <form method="PUT" action="/admin/professions-update/{{ $data->pkprofession }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="profession_name">Profession Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="profession_name" id="profession_name" class="form-control" value="{{$data->profession_name}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@stop
```

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/admin/professions-edit/{id}', 'v1\ProfessionsController@edit');
Route::put('/admin/professions-update/{id}', 'v1\ProfessionsController@update');
```

And Here are the methods being called:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = PdTprofession::find($id);
        return view('professions-edit', compact('data'));
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = PdTprofession::find($id);
        return view('professions-edit', compact('data'));
    }
```

Why am I getting a 404 error and how do I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: dont use method=PUT 
Use method=post and add @method('PUT') in your form, and dont forget csrf token

Comment: Try with <form method="POST" action="/admin/professions-update/{{ $data->pkprofession }}">@csrf @method("PUT")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **In laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing), HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE
>   actions. So, when defining PUT, PATCH or DELETE routes that are called
>   from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden _method field to the
>   form. The value sent with the _method field will be used as the HTTP
>   request method:**

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

You may use the @method Blade directive to generate the _method input:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, especially for the _token part.

Comment: You're welcome mate! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: This answer has been accepted, had to wait a few minutes

Answer (score 3):

There are so many issues in your code lets resolve one by one:

```
action="/admin/professions-update/{{ $data->pkprofession }}">
```

change it to:

```
action="{{ url('/admin/professions-update/' . $data->pkprofession) }}">
```

and then HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions, so chage it to:

```
<form action="{{ url('/admin/professions-update/' . $data->pkprofession) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf  // this is required when you are using the method other then 'get'
    other elements
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `csrf` token and the `method` input. Try this:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'AdminLTE')

@section('content_header')
    <h1>Professions</h1>
@stop

@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="/admin/professions-update/{{ $data->pkprofession }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="profession_name">Profession Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="profession_name" id="profession_name" class="form-control" value="{{$data->profession_name}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
@stop
```

Also, in your `update` method you are forgeting to update the object, add this to your code:

```
$data->update($request->all());
```

For more info: [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)